# How to hide message pandas dataframe if query not find data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

this my code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/jupyternotebook/template1.csv')

print(df.query("Reg == 'REG01'").apply( lambda row:row["Severity"]+"/"+row["Category"]+"/"+row["IncidentNumber"]+"/"+row['zmii_ServiceImpact'] +"/"+row['mttr'], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True).to_string())
```

Result

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [IncidentNumber, zmii_AffectedRegion, zmii_ServiceImpact, Severity, zmii_IncidentStartTime, zmii_ProblemClearTime, mttr, zmii_AffectedSite, Ne, Reg, Category, mttr.1]
Index: []
```

I want hide message above if dataframe empty while query

from above to no message/clear text

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. There's an existing question about how to check if a dataframe is empty, which, once you know that, you just need to write an `if`, so that effectively answers your question. Just in case you're not sure how to apply it exactly, you can [edit] to clarify. BTW, check out [ask] for tips, like starting with your own research and showing what you've tried.